# K-means initialization with further-first traversal and k-mean++

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am confused about k-mean++ initialization. I understand k-mean++ choose and furthest data point as next data center. But how about outlier? What is the different between `initialization with further-first traversal and k-mean++ ?

I saw someone explain in this way:

> ---
>
> Here is a one-dimensional example. Our observations are [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Let the first center, c1, be 0. The probability that the next
>   cluster center, c2, is x is proportional to ||c1-x||^2. So, P(c2 = 1)
>   = 1a, P(c2 = 2) = 4a, P(c2 = 3) = 9a, P(c2 = 4) = 16a, where a = 1/(1+4+9+16).
>
> Suppose c2=4. Then, P(c3 = 1) = 1a, P(c3 = 2) = 4a, P(c3 = 3) = 1a,
>   where a = 1/(1+4+1).
>
> ---

What is this array or list is [0,1,2,4,5,6,100]. Obviously, 100 is the outlier in this case and it will be chosen as the data center at some point. Can someone give a better explanation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means chooses points with *probability*.

But yes, with extreme outliers it is likely to chose the outlier.

That is *fine*, because so will k-means. Most likely the best SSQ solution has a one-element cluster containing only that point.

If you have such data, the k-means solutions tend to be rather useless, and you probably should choose another algorithm such as DBSCAN instead.